# VB.net Integer Counting Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, sharpdevelop

So I'm learning VB.NET and I kinda have this newbie question and I couldn't find answers anywhere on the web.

[image: The program]

This program is supposed to be counter. Every time the button is clicked the label should update. Here's my code for the MouseClick Listener every time the button is clicked:

```
Sub Button2MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim starter As String
    Dim int1 As Integer 
    Dim int2 As Integer 
    Dim ender As String
    starter =label2.Text
    int1 = CInt(starter)
    int2 = (int1 + 1)
    ender = CStr(int2)
    label2.Text = ender
End Sub
```

The program works but here's the problem. It only works up until number 9. Once it is supposed to display "10" is just displays 1 and when it is supposed to display 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, and 19, it only displays "1" (the first digit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest that probably, the issue is that you've sized the label control so that it can only show a single digit.

If you go back to the form designer and make that label control bigger, you should start to be able to see the second digit.

Comment: Also take a look at the label's `AutoSize` property. Set it to True if you want the label to expand if it's not big enough to display its contents.